# How to extract zip folders and look for specific file names Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code currently unzips a zip folder and runs through each file in that folder. However, I need it to read a specific filename called "file.txt" within that zip folder. I tried to only read "file.txt" from the zip folder but it just ends up running all the files in that folder. Any suggestions? My code outputs to a text file and all I need it to read is the "file.txt" but it reads all of the files that ends with ".txt" as seen in the actual result

```
    import re
    import os
    from zipfile import ZipFile
    def pan():
        print("Extract single file from ZIP")
        with ZipFile('input_files.zip', 'r') as zipObj:
            listOfFileNames = zipObj.namelist()
            #zipObj.extractall()
            for fileName in listOfFileNames:
                if fileName.endswith('.txt'):
                    zipObj.read(fileName, 'file.txt') 
    ##def main():
        comma_string = ', '
        outfile = "output2.txt"                 #this will be the filename that the code will write to 
        wp_string = " White Space Detected"          
        tab_string = " tab detected"
        mc_string = " Missing carriage return"
        ne_string = " No Error"                 #If there is no whitespace,tabs, then there is no error
        baconFile = open(outfile,"wt") 
        print('Filename\tLine\tnumber of numbers\tstring separated by a comma\twhite space found\ttab found\tcarriage return found\n')         #This prints the master column in the python shell and this is the way the code should collect the data 
        baconFile.write('Filename\tLine\tnumber of numbers\tstring separated by a comma\twhite space found\ttab found\tcarriage return found\n') #This prints the master column in the output file and this is the way the code should collect the data

        for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd() + "/input_files"):
            with open("input_files/" + filename, 'r') as f:
                output_contents(filename, f, baconFile)
        baconFile.close()       #closes the for loop that the code is writing to


    def output_contents(filename, f, baconFile):     #using open() function to open the file inside the directory
        index = 0
        for line in f:
                                        #create a list of all of the numerical values in our line
            content = line.split(',')       #this will be used to count the amount numbers before and after comma
            whitespace_found = False
            tab_found = False
            false_string = "False (end of file)"
            carriage_found = false_string 
            sigfigs = ""

            index += 1                            #adds 1 for every line if it finds what the command wants

            if " " in line:                         #checking for whitespace
                whitespace_found = True
            if "\t" in line:                        #checking for tabs return
                tab_found = True
            if '\n' in line:                    #checking if there is a newline after the end of each line
                carriage_found = True                                        
            sigfigs = (','.join(str(len(g)) for g in re.findall(r'\d+\.?(\d+)?', line )))    #counts the sigsfigs after decimal point 

            print(filename + "\t{0:<4}\t{1:<17}\t{2:<27}\t{3:17}\t{4:9}\t{5:21}"
              .format(index, len(content), sigfigs, str(whitespace_found), str(tab_found), str(carriage_found)))   #whatever is inside the .format() is the way it the data is stored into
            baconFile.write('\n')
            baconFile.write( filename + "\t{0:<4}\t{1:<17}\t{2:<27}\t{3:17}\t{4:9}\t{5:21}"
                        .format(index, len(content), sigfigs, str(whitespace_found), str(tab_found), str(carriage_found)))



    if __name__ == '__main__':
        #main()
        pan()
```

Expected:

```
Filename    Line    number of numbers   string separated by a comma white space found   tab found   carriage return found

file.txt    1       3                   0,3,4                       False               False       True                 
file.txt    2       3                   0,0,1                       True                True        True                 
file.txt    3       3                   7,3,0,1                     False               False       True                 
file.txt    4       1                   1                           False               False       True                 
file.txt    5       3                   5,0,1                       False               False       False (end of file)
```

Actual:

```
Filename    Line    number of numbers   string separated by a comma white space found   tab found   carriage return found

alot.txt    1       3                   0,3,4                       False               False       True                 
alot.txt    2       3                   0,0,1                       True                True        True                 
alot.txt    3       3                   7,3,0,1                     False               False       True                 
alot.txt    4       1                   1                           False               False       True                 
alot.txt    5       3                   5,0,1                       False               False       False (end of file)  
file.txt    1       3                   0,3,4                       False               False       True                 
file.txt    2       3                   0,0,1                       True                True        True                 
file.txt    3       3                   5,0,1                       False               False       False (end of file)  
file_2.txt  1       3                   0,3,4                       False               False       True                 
file_2.txt  2       3                   0,0,1                       True                True        True                 
file_2.txt  3       3                   5,0,1                       False               False       False (end of file)  
INCOME.txt  1       3                   0,3,4                       False               False       True                 
INCOME.txt  2       3                   0,0,1                       True                True        True                 
INCOME.txt  3       3                   5,0,1                       False               False       True                 
INCOME.txt  4       3                   4,3,0                       True                True        True                 
INCOME.txt  5       3                   7,3,0,1                     False               False       True                 
INCOME.txt  6       1                   1                           False               False       False (end of file)
```

Comment: `fileName.endswith('file.txt'):`

Comment: why reading all .txt files if all you want is just one file with the name file.txt? As @furas mentioned, try the file name explicitly in the `endswith()` function.

Comment: I did try that but it still reads all .txt files @VigneshSP

Comment: Most likely those records are in *file.txt*.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks!